# Setting password for android app using lock screen patterns

Tags: android, pattern-matching, design-patterns, lockscreen

I want to set a password for my application which it will require at the time of execution. I want that it should be like lock screen patterns, is it possible?
If yes please help me out to find some helpful material to design lock screen as I have absolutely no idea how to start with it. I've read touch event of Developer.android.com but don't how to proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:
https://code.google.com/p/android-lockpattern/source/browse/src/group/pals/android/lib/ui/lockpattern/widget/LockPatternUtils.java?r=7470bc287cba61198430e3d8aff32196bb5824a0

Please, give an information whether it works or not. :)

Comment: I already have seen it, but unfortunately unable to understand this. I downloaded this code but it shows target framework error. :(